# Netty + NioDatagram(UDP) + ProtoBuf issue - Discarded inbound message DatagramPacket

Tags: udp, netty, protocol-buffers

I am trying to build a UDP server using netty with NioDatagramChannel and protoBuf as the message. Here is the server implementation:

```
EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
try {
  Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
  b.group(group)
      .channel(NioDatagramChannel.class)
      .option(ChannelOption.SO_BROADCAST, true)
      .handler(new UdpProtoBufServerChannelInitializer());

  b.bind(port).sync().channel().closeFuture().await();
} finally {
  group.shutdownGracefully();
}
```

UdpProtoBufServerChannelInitializer:

```
public class UdpProtoBufServerChannelInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<NioDatagramChannel> {

    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UdpProtoBufServerChannelInitializer.class);
    @Override
      protected void initChannel(NioDatagramChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
        p.addFirst(new ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder());
        p.addFirst(new ProtobufDecoder(Message.getDefaultInstance()));
        p.addFirst(new ProtobufVarint32LengthFieldPrepender());
        p.addFirst(new ProtobufEncoder());

        p.addFirst(new UdpProtoBufServerHandler());
    }
  }
```

However, I am seeing the following error after receiving message from java client before running UdpProtoBufServerChannelInitializer.

DEBUG DefaultChannelPipeline:76 - Discarded inbound message DatagramPacket(/127.0.0.1:60556 => 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:55559, PooledUnsafeHeapByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 34, cap: 2048)) that reached at the tail of the pipeline. Please check your pipeline configuration.

Also, not sure if this exception when launching the application is related:

```
    2017-05-22 14:31:09 DEBUG PlatformDependent0:91 - jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray(int): unavailable
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$6.run(PlatformDependent0.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0.<clinit>(PlatformDependent0.java:288)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.getSystemClassLoader(PlatformDependent.java:895)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.isAndroid0(PlatformDependent.java:919)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.<clinit>(PlatformDependent.java:70)
    at io.netty.util.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:32)
    at io.netty.util.Signal$1.<init>(Signal.java:27)
    at io.netty.util.Signal.<clinit>(Signal.java:27)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.<clinit>(DefaultPromise.java:43)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:36)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:58)
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:52)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:87)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:82)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:63)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:51)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:43)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all. I figured out the way to do this, finally:

```
public class DatagramServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DatagramPacket> {

  @Override
  protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket packet) throws Exception {
      Message message = SocketProtos.Message.parseFrom(packet.content().nioBuffer());
      ctx.writeAndFlush(packet.retain());
  }

  @Override
  public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
      cause.printStackTrace();
      ctx.close();
   }
}
```

Just use the NioDatagram UDP standard implementation and then parse the message into byte[] to ProtoBuf message.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like your pipeline has no consumers. You should put your custom handler, where you process your data. You can do it before `p.addFirst(new ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder());` with `p.addFirst(new MyHandler());` or after `p.addFirst(new UdpProtoBufServerHandler());` with `p.addLast(new MyHandler());`.

And in fact, I can assume that you want to use `addLast` instead of `addFirst` in your code. If you use `addLast` you'll get the order as you declare it in the pipeline `ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder -> ProtobufDecoder -> ... -> UdpProtoBufServerHandler`. In your case (with `addFirst`) you get `UdpProtoBufServerHandler -> ProtobufEncoder -> ... -> ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder` that looks wrong because you have a handler at the first position and a decoder at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. After changing to addLast, I am still seeing the same error. This is my implementation:

    `ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
    p.addLast(new UdpProtoBufServerHandler());
    p.addLast(new ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder());
    p.addLast(new ProtobufDecoder(Message.getDefaultInstance()));p.addLast(new ProtobufVarint32LengthFieldPrepender());
    p.addLast(new ProtobufEncoder());

    p.addLast(new UdpProtoBufServerHandler());`